# What 2.5 in. adapter for mSata SSD?

Tags: ssd, adapter, msata

I bought an SSD for my laptop, not knowing there are different form factors and what I got is mSata. It's a tiny thing. Deciding to get an adapter, I want to be sure I get the correct one, and I don't want reduced performance. The Amazon title is "Crucial MX200 250GB mSATA Internal Solid State Drive - CT250MX200SSD3" seen at  [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00RQA6LFA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RQA6LFA) . Please give recommendations.

Comment: I looked at the stack exchange meta site for what forum to post my question. In three different places it said superuser is the correct forum. This is because there is no hardware forum as such. My question is not off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I was very curious about this post and I started to do some research. I didn't know there were such things as mSATA drives. I found an adapter [SY-ADA40050](https://sybausa.com/productInfo.php?iid=1210) which boast "No Sacrifice on the mSATA SSD Performance". Shop around you might find a good price for it.

Comment: I saw a similar item. I think an adapter can be found that does not reduce performance. Most likely, none will reduce performance. I'm hoping someone with experience will post. My main concern is for the mSata SSD to fit the adapter, There seems to be different physical sizes. I found http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00J1EQH5I , but am waiting to buy it until I see more posts here. An issue is said to be heat dissipation and metal is said to be better.